# Odd behavior with a gzip compressed file

Tags: filesystems, rhel, mount, nfs

I've got a very bizarre issue occurring with a Redhat system. We have a Gzip-compressed TAR file that contains hundreds of small text files with absolute paths. It's only 8 MB. We copy this file to a mounted ext3 HDD and it hangs, causing a system crash and reboot. I think the O.S. is eventually sending a SIGTERM to the "cp" process. Not much in the sys logs.

I can't do too much debugging since this is a remote system that I don't have direct access to. I'm not looking for a direct answer, since I didn't give a lot of info. However, I figure someone might mention something I haven't thought of yet to spark further, independent investigation. This is somewhat specific, so to make this a more general discusion:

- Is there anything in Unix that would cause "cp" (or the underlying system calls) to treat compressed archives differently than any other file?
- What about an ext3 mounted harddrive? Any reason to handle *compressed archives* differently?
- NFS... We are obtaining the file via NFS source. Any reason NFS should handle it specially?

Comment: My first guess would be hardware failure...

Comment: Please clarify "hangs, system crash, and reboot". Even in the case of most hardware failures, that should leave some evidence around. The `dmesg` command will give you a peek into the kernel's "error reporting of last resort".

Comment: By hang, I mean the system becomes fully unresponsive. Cannot establish SSH connection, cannot kill the active "cp" process, and hence cannot open a new terminal to strace or check vmstat.

Comment: System crash means the OS finally kills the process (I see the SIGTERM in the sys logs) - followed by a graceful reboot of the system. I will note that the reboot *might* have been initiated by the user. I can't tell from the log, but based on the timestamps and when I think the user was at the terminal, I think it was triggered by the system.

Comment: SIGTERM followed by graceful reboot sounds like the behavior of `shutdown`. The Linux OOM process killer uses SIGKILL and NFS faults should return EIO to the cp process and will _not_ send a signal. Alas, it sounds like you've got a rogue operator at the remote site; that's gonna make diagnosis tough. In fact, until you fix the "dueling operators" problem through human protocols, you're kinda stuck.

Comment: Is the remote system running out of inodes on the disk when you attempt to expand this file? If it's NFS mounted you should be able to run the `df -i` command and see if this is the issue.

Comment: @msw - a rogue operator issue seems unlikely if the Op is having the same problem all the time at the same point of trying the same commands, don't you think?

Answer (score 7):

So if I'm reading your question correctly you're doing:

```
$ cp /nfs/mnt/foo.tar.gz /local/ext3/drive
```

and the system crashes. I'd try isolating:

```
$ cat /nfs/mnt/foo.tar.gz > /dev/null
```

to check if it is the NFS system, and then

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=/local/ext3/drive/zeros bs=1K count=8000
```

to check writes to the local file system. If both of those come up clean, I'd be surprised because:

1. `cp` has no idea that the data it is copying is compressed
2. nor does an ext3 filesystem
3. NFS shouldn't care, but I can imagine some obscure scenarios where it just might, but then the `cat` test above should catch it.

Comment: Great idea in regards to NFS... I'm having the user try this now. As for the "dd" command - we have had this issue happen every time using 4 different disks, all of which are brand spanking new. So I'm hesitant to say it's disk related. Moreover, we have copied a variety of files, from B's in size to GB's with no issue.